# Como poderia implementar Command (Design Pattern) nesse trabalho?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Estou fazendo um trabalho em Java, onde devemos implementar 3 Design Patterns a partir do software que criamos anteriormente. 
O software que eu criei é basicamente um CRUD para filmes. Em uma aba, você adiciona (insert) e altera (update) os registros e na outra aba você tem uma visualização dos registros da seguinte maneira:
 
[image: Visualizaçao dos registros]

[image: Parte de cadastro]

Como esse trabalho utiliza banco de dados, eu já usei duas Design Patterns: Singleton (eu li que ela é muito criticada, etc. mas só estamos usando para aprender mesmo) e DAO (dei uma estudada na internet e consegui implementar).

O professor, se bem me lembro, recomendou a Command, mas fui dar uma lida nela e não consegui enxergar uma forma de encaixá-la no código. Como eu poderia implementá-la aqui?

Comment: vou deixar para quem quiser comentar pois a resposta seria muito longa rs. Strategy no seu DAO, Command<Entrada, Saida> para executar as ações da tela e Singleton como você disse, para recuperar conexões do banco de dados por exemplo.

Comment: Acho que um que ficaria bom seria o MVC.

Comment: Então, como funcionaria um Command para as ações da tela nesse caso? Vou dar uma lida no MVC e Strategy tbm.

Comment: O Swing possui suporte a [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) (implementação do `Command Pattern`). O exemplo clássico é ter um opção no Menu que faz a mesma coisa do que determinado componente da UI (e.g., Atualizar / Fechar, etc).

Comment: Veja  que eventos e listeners também são implementações da [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Os containers e componentes da janela seguem a [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Provavelmente você usou a  [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) sem saber na hora de decorar componentes com scrolls... Na real, sendo absolutamente preguiçoso, você pode justificar que seu trabalho está pronto simplesmente por ter utilizado *Swing* hehehe.

Comment: Hmm entendi. Muito obrigado pelas respostas, pessoal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mais mole de fazer é o Design Pattern [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).  Por exemplo, na classe filme ficaria algo assim:

```
class Filme {

   private String nome;
   private Date duracao;
   ...


   /** Setters **/

   public Filme setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        return this;
   }

   public Filme setDuracao(Date duracao) {
        this.duracao = duracao;
        return this;
   }
   .....

}
```

Daí na hora de usar é algo assim:

```
...
    Filme filme = new Filme().setNome("Terminator").setDuracao(duracao);
...
```

Ou assim:

```
...
    Filme filme = new Filme();
    filme.setNome("Terminator").setDuracao(duracao);
...
```